# How to Style text in Textarea Container?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a textarea tag in My modal for editing.

When I want to show my note in textarea, it shows text in center of the textarea box.

I try text-alighn,direction and float,also I tried to put my note in p tag,but I does not work.

all that I do,is shown I picture.
[image]

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show us all the styles applied to the textares Looks like something in admin_base.css could be the one causing problems.

Comment: Please share your code instead of screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add `dir="rtl"` to the `div` wrapper of the `textarea`:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: use `"` and not `”` as :`dir="rtl"`

Comment: It’s just phone formatting. Have no possibility to add straight quotes. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

this CSS code can align your text from the right for Farsi

```
   textarea {
        white-space: normal;
        text-align: right;
        -moz-text-align-last: right; /* Firefox 12+ */
        text-align-last: right;
        direction: rtl;
    }
```

and your HTML can be like this

```
<div id="wrap">

  <textarea class="area" col="2" row="5">این نوشته از راست است.</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: >Codepen link that you can check online https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/roNMbp

Answer (score -1):

```
   use text-align:left !important
   or float:left !important
```